# Проверка процессов критический или нет

Tags: c#, процесс

Какой самый надёжный метод определения системных процессов в системе?

Использую данный способ:

```
namespace MoreInfoTest
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.Title = "Process check is critical";
            try
            {
                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (!IsProcessCritical(process))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.ProcessName.ToString()} is normal.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.ProcessName.ToString()} is critical.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private const uint ProcessBreakOnTermination = 29;

        public static bool IsProcessCritical(Process pr)
        {

            uint val = 0;
            if (NativeMethods.NtQueryInformationProcess(pr.Handle, ProcessBreakOnTermination, ref val, sizeof(uint), out int size) != 0 || size != sizeof(uint))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception("NtQueryInformationProcess failed");
            }
            return val != 0;
        }
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
   [DllImport("NTDLL.DLL")]
   internal static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr hProcess, uint pic,ref uint pi, int cb, out int pSize);
}
```

Выводит список всего из пару процессов и то не все критичные пример на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй способ тоже не так работает:

```
 bool criticalProcess = false;
 foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
 {
   if (!NativeMethods.IsProcessCritical(process.Handle, ref criticalProcess))
   {
      continue; // Если не удалось получить информацию по процессам.
   }
   if (criticalProcess)
   {
     Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.ProcessName.ToString()} is critical");
   }
   else
   {
     Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.ProcessName.ToString()} is not critical");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess), то говорится, что используемый метод устарел и начиная с Windows 8.1 следует использовать другой:

> ProcessBreakOnTermination
>   29
>   Retrieves a ULONG value indicating whether the process is considered critical.
>
> **Note**  This value can be used starting in Windows XP with SP3. Starting in Windows 8.1, [IsProcessCritical](https://msdn.microsoft.com/A5ED8672-B4C3-4A31-8B3F-A181628219A4) should be used instead.

У тебя явно скриншот с Win10, а значит, надо воспользоваться функцией [IsProcessCritical](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-isprocesscritical). Если верить [pinvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll.IsProcessCritical), то она объявляется так:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool IsProcessCritical(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool Critical);
```

Comment: Как раз читал про это). И обновил вопрос, такая же проблема.

Comment: @r3xq1, заработало? И в чём проблема была?